# What will actually happen to my 3 phase motor -- low and unbalanced voltage?

Tags: motor, three-phase

Dr.Google tells me:

"Voltage unbalance exceeding more than 2 percent in three-phase systems can cause current unbalance among the windings. These, in turn, can cause an increase in winding temperature and an overheating problem that can be harmful to the motor."

Which I fully understand, however what is the real world consequence?

Specifically I have a motor running a pressure washer pump.  I can adjust the load on the pump by adjusting the pressure.  To be effective it is better to run the pump close to its upper limit.

Speks:

MEREK : AERO / AEROMAX
TYPE : AE -112M-2
POWER : 5.5hp / 4kw / 5.5pk
RPM : 2880 (2POLE / 2P)
AMPERE : 8.2
VOLT : 220/380V / 3PHASE
MODEL : FOOT MOUNTED (B3)
DIAMETER AS : 28mm
GULUNGAN : TEMBAGA

I put in a cheep volt/amp meter so I can adjust the pressure until one phase reaches a max of 8 amps.

Now the onion……  the local power supplier is not great…….

Most of the time I get about 200-220v per phase, ex 200v, 212v, 220v.   But lately around dinner time when demand is up it drops….. a lot.   It has be down to 180 volts on one phase and the other 2 in the 200-220v range.

So I have been dropping the pressure and making sure the pump is not pulling more than 8 amps.

Obviously this is not good!  But I can’t really do anything about the power coming in anytime soon, and I can’t stop work so……

Any idea what's going to happen to my motor? and how fast?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any way for you to add a boost transformer on the weak phase? Also, what is the waveform on that problematic phase? Perhaps you can connect a good power analyzer or V-A-W meter to see how much power is being consumed compared to the actual pump output. And temperature should be monitored.

Comment: Side-step the problem and don't run the pressure washer during peak demand/brown out.